# How can I find out how many characters fit in the remaining space in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text box with a certain width and a string. How do I know how many characters fit from the end of the string until the end of the line?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to fill the rest of the TextBox with some other characters? Then you could just use Graphics.MeasureString (I didn't look it up, but I think that's the methods name)

Comment: Unless you are using a fixed-width font, which is rare anymore, there is no fixed answer to this question.  Unless you know what characters you will be inserting after your string; then you can use Graphics.MeasureString to determine their size.  (And the size of your existing string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of characters that will fit depends on the font and what characters they are. If you know what characters you will use, or are using a fixed-width font, you can use [Graphics.MeasureString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

you can't, first because different characters take up different widths and second because text is rendered differently on different platforms.